# How to make a simple C server, which accept only one connection at the same time

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, sockets, tcp

I'm trying to make a simple C server (for testing my python clients). The main rule is that server must accept only one connection at the same time. Server should work like the loop with `accept` function in it. Server should accept or reject clients. If client is accepted, server should continue listening for new connections and reject them.

My python client looks like this.

```
import threading
import time
import socket

SERVER_ADDRESS = 'some ip'
SERVER_PORT = 12345


def connect_to_server():
    client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    try:
        client_socket.connect((SERVER_ADDRESS, SERVER_PORT))
        print("Client connected successfully to the server.", threading.current_thread())
    except ConnectionRefusedError:
        print("Connection refused: Unable to connect to the server.")
    except ConnectionAbortedError:
        print("Connection aborted: Connection with the server aborted.")
    except ConnectionResetError:
        print("Connection reset: Connection with the server was reset.")
    finally: 
        time.sleep(10000)
    
connect_to_server()
```

The problem is that with `accept` C function I can't get `ConnectionRefusedError` on my client.
I understand that server firstly accept the client and than disconnect it, but is there any variant to get `ConnectionRefusedError` immediately after server socket closure? Without sending or receiving any messages into socket from client.

I'm not good in C, so I ased this question in ChatGPT, but his solution doesn't fit my conditions.

So, is it actually possible?

Comment: You could always close the server socket after accepting a client. Drawback is that then some other process could reuse the socket. I would try `listen(sockfd, 0);` after accepting a client. And when the client disconnects `listen(sockfd, 1);` to accept the next client again.

Comment: As I have already told you in your duplicate, why disconnect anybody? Just single-thread the server. Pending clients will then queue in the backlog queue and be serviced in turn.